# Continue migration if there is an interruption

Tags: java, database, liquibase, changelog

I was running a migration using a CustomChange and it was aborted. I want to continue but it is `waiting for the change lock` . I was able to solve the problem by using the command `mvn liquiabase:releaseLocks` but I wanted to implement a mechanism where the block would release itself when running the migration again. Is is possible to do it? I tried to implement a method in the custom class but it´s not called when doing `mvn liquibase:update`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest determining the root cause of the Liquibase failure that is leaving the lock set in the databasechangeloglock table.  It seems very unusual that this happens that frequently that you would to need to build something into your execution to handle it.  You will probably just be covering up a problem that needs to be addressed.